# Image in custom header with react-navigation is flickering / blinking on navigating

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have my own HeaderComponent with an image:

```
const CustomHeaderLogo = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Image
        source={require("../assets/logo.png")}
        style={{ width: 160, height: 30 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default CustomHeaderLogo;
```

which I use in `navigationOptions` in stackNavigator on all my screens like this:

```
navigationOptions: {
   headerTitle: () => <HeaderLogo />
}
```

It works but the problem is, that the image is flickering / blinking when navigating from screen to screen. That's especially noticeable on iOS.

Is there any way to prevent the image from flickering?

**EDIT**: Need to edit my question since I now know where the flickering is coming from.

It is the animation effect in the header. I still don't know how to disable it since `animationEnabled` setting to false doesn't change anything. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator#animationenabled

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?